# Restricting access to a single MultiSite site based on IP -- possible?

Tags: admin, ip

I have need to restrict not just admin access but also access to the content stored on a single site in a MultiSite network based upon a user's IP address.

1. Is this even possible?
2. Is there an easily admin-able plugin?

(I *could* restrict access using something like Justin Tadlock's "Members" plugin, but the requirement in this case is based on IP.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about more extensive solutions but this can be accomplished with tiny plugin which will check IP (in [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) at some stage of load and die on match.

Had you looked through official repository? There is [IP tag](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/ip).